What is the maximum amount of data that can be retrieved by the vector search API?
In version 2.4.0, when the search API is called without the limit parameter, it retrieves 10 results.
When the limit parameter is provided, according to the documentation

the maximum value supported is 16,384. Is there any way to retrieve more data in a single request?

Use an iterator to retrieve the full data in batches.
https://milvus.io/docs/with-iterators.md#With-Iterators
